# Shortestpath for each node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find a shortestpath to a nearby node with certain props. This one works:

```
match (st:station {kind:'Small'})
with st limit 1 
match p =  ShortestPath((st) - [:installation|cable*1..25] - (st1:station )  )
where st1.kind IN ['Biggest', 'Bigger', 'Big'] AND ALL(idx in filter ( x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = 'Connection') WHERE idx.switch= 'Closed')
with st, st1 
match p2 = ShortestPath((st) - [:installation|cable*1..25] - (st1) )
where ALL(idx in filter ( x IN relationships(p2) WHERE type(x) = 'Connection') WHERE idx.switch= 'Closed')
with st, p2 order by length(p2) limit 1 
with st, head(tail(filter ( x IN relationships(p2) WHERE type(x) = 'Connection'))) as vb
set vb.feeding='True', st.done='True' )
```

It finds the Dijkstra SSSP shortest paths forrest from which I subsequently take the shortest one (determined by doing multiple shortestpaths with FIXED endpoints).

When I leave out the first 'limit 1' the query never returns and no updates are done. When using limit 2 or 3, the FIRST node found is updated, none other.

What am I missing here? Anyone?

Comment: Is this the whole query? it looks like it's missing something since there is no `RETURN` clause? Also, I'd recommend doing some refactoring to speed up your query, perhaps for example chaning `station.kind` to a label, and, if it makes sense in your model, assigning directions to `installation` and `cable` relationships. The `1..25` will make a huge scan, and by the sounds of your algorithm's requirements, it looks like you may need to use `unwind` in place of the first `with`. But I'd need to see more of the query...

Comment: Dom, This the whole query. The set clause takes care of the return.

Comment: Due to import restrictions ( GIS system with topology ) I have a chain of (station) (installation)  ( [ connection ] > (cable) < [connection] )* (installation) (station) you might guess, I'm modeling a utility network.)
I tried unwind, it generates a syntax error.
I reverted to Dijkstra, because it's the faster algoritm. With a fixed starting node it takes about 1.5 secs (10 cable hobs ). If doing a straignt scan it doesn't return at all. Before I look at performance, I first want to see it work (e.g. more then 1 set done)

Comment: Could you post your original `unwind` query so I can get a picture of what you're trying to do? My PhD is in this area (literally modelling utility networks in neo4j, from a historical perspective), and I'd love to hear more about your model and try to offer help and learn from it!

Comment: Dom,
For a specific node I use
match (st:station {number:123456})
with st
..........
but I want do run it for ALL station {kind:'Small'}.
I replaced 'with st' for 'unwind st' but than it says something like 'collection expected, but got Node'.
The network is heavily redundant (midvoltage distribution) and I want to pick out just one path of powerflow.
I tried your suggestion propagatiing the property to a label, but it is actually slower.

Comment: I actually don't need the second 'shortestpath', the SSSP forrest already consists of these diferent paths, I only have to sort them and pick the first.

Comment: with unwind I get to this:
`profile match (sts:station {kind:'Small'} ) 
with collect(sts)  as csts 
unwind csts as st 
with st limit 1
optional match p =  ShortestPath((st) - [:installation|cable*1..25] - (st1:BIGGER)  )
where ALL(idx in filter ( x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = 'Connection') WHERE idx.switch= 'Closed')
with st, head(tail(filter ( x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = 'Connection'))) as vb, p order by length(p) limit 1 
set vb.voedend='True'
set st.done='True'`
(set label BIGGER on station.kind in ['BIG','BIGGER','BIGGEST'] )
Still not looping

Comment: `with collect(sts) as csts unwind csts as st` is effectively a no-op (but wastes time and resources). Also, your filters require all relationships to be of type `Connection` but your `MATCH` pattern only matches paths containing just the `installation` and `cable` relationship types, so your query is not doing what you probably intended. Finally, as your said, you need to get rid of the second shortestpath.

Comment: Can you correct the filtering or the `MATCH` patterns in your question?

Comment: Cybersam, you are right, I translated wrong. Cable should be Connection. For the filter: I am filtering the Connections for being all with switch=closed. It does allow for other nodes and relationships to be in the path.  Actually I us the collect()..... to limit the input node stream. It actually does what it supposed to do for limit 1. For limit 2 it will do the first node but no other. if I leave the collect() sequence out, same result (test it by finding nodes which have done='True'). How can I upload teh profile? It seems odd!.

Comment: I think I understand. 'with' is a sort of implicit 'collect and unwind', so there is no 'looping'. "with' propagates complete result sets only. So the second 'with' probably only propagates the last ( = 1 ) result. Makes sense?